# How to do Page Redirection based on two drop down menu selections?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to create a form from my website where the user has two dropdown boxes with values say `body height` and `type of build`. Depending on their selection, they would be directed to a page with information about their specific/selected build.

To have an idea of what I want to create, here is the form i wish to display.. the use if for a BMX bike guide

> function goToPage() {   var type =
>   document.getElementById("type").value;   var height =
>   document.getElementById("height").value;
>   
>     if(type !== 0 && height !== 0)   {
>               window.location = "http://www.maltabmx.com/About.html?jtype=" + 
>               1 + "&height=" + 
>               1;
>
> ```
>         window.location = "http://www.maltabmx.com/Footage.html?jtype=" + 
>         1 + "&height=" + 
>         2;
>
>         window.location = "http://www.maltabmx.com?jtype=" + 
>         1 + "&height=" + 
>         3;
>
>         window.location = "http://www.maltabmx.com/About.html?jtype=" + 
>         1 + "&height=" + 
>         4;
>
>         window.location = "http://www.maltabmx.com/Footage.html?jtype=" + 
>         1 + "&height=" + 
>         5;
>
>         window.location = "http://www.maltabmx.com?jtype=" + 
>         1 + "&height=" + 
>         6;   }  }
> ```
>
> ```
> <form>  <p> Type of Terrain: </p>
> ```
>
> Select
>       Street/Park
>       Dirt
>       Racing
>
> ```
> <p>Body Height</p>
> <select id="height">
> <option value="0" id="Select">Select</option>
> <option value="1" id="5ft">4ft</option>
> <option value="2" id="5.5ft">4.25ft</option>
> <option value="3" id="5.5ft">4.50ft</option>
> <option value="4" id="6ft">4.75ft</option>
> <option value="5" id="5ft">5ft</option>
> <option value="6" id="5.5ft">5.25ft</option>
> <option value="7" id="6ft">5.50ft</option>    <option value="8" id="5ft">5.75ft</option>
> <option value="9" id="5.5ft">6ft</option>
> <option value="10" id="6ft">6.25ft</option>
> </select>
>
> <br /><br />
>
> <input  onclick="goToPage();"  type="button" value="Submit" />
>
> </form>
> ```

Comment: after you check your $_GET or $_POST values display the correct information, or redirect the script to the page that does. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited my post with the form i have done till now, so you could have an idea of what i wish to create

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
 <head>

  $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#submit').click(function(){ 

      var type= $("#type").val();
      var height = $("#height").val();

      window.location.href = 'http://www.someweb.com/page.php?type='+type+'&&height='+height;

    });

 });

  </head>
  <body>

 <form>
 <p> Type of Terrain: </p>

  <select id="type">
    <option value="1" id="Street">Street</option>
    <option value="2" id="Dirt">Dirt</option>
    <option value="3" id="Park">Park</option>
    <option value="4" id="Racing">Racing</option>
    </select>

    <p>Body Height</p>
    <select id="Height">
    <option value="1" id="5ft">5ft</option>
    <option value="2" id="5.5ft">5.5ft</option>
    <option value="3" id="6ft">6ft</option>

    </select>

    <br /><br />

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, i changed the code above. Let me know if you still hve some questions.

PS: normally to redirect or pass values to other pages you would want to use the jquery $.post, $.get or $.ajax  methods instead of windows.location.href.

Have a look here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

EDITED - Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/YXW7K/13/

Comment: could you please help me indicate how i would link the code to the form above.. sry but im very bad at coding still starting off

Comment: Please be nice to users of assistive technology and provide a submit button rather than auto submitting the form when the select is changed. See [WCAG Failure 36](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20120103/F36)

Comment: So, i changed the code above. Let me know if you still hve some questions

Comment: i have edited the code above in my question with yours to my use but nothing happens when i press the submit button, am i missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: i have managed to make code to work but do u now how i can make it more efficient as im gonna have over 100 lines of code 

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, here http://jsfiddle.net/YXW7K/11/ a working solution. Don't get caught up with using raw javascript, better use jQuery for ordinary things. cheers and remember most of the business logic to be executed is at server side once u pass ur parameters to it.

Comment: thanks so much for your help, but when i copy it to my html document nothing happens when i press submit and how do I direct the users to a page and not an alert window? Thanks again

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/YXW7K/13/ .  The submit works because you see the alert, you wouldnt see it otherwise. The alert is just an example for you to see what url is being created.        The javascript portion of the fiddle has to be placed inside a <script></script> in the head of the html.